# 4 Bytes memory address to 32-bit hex value

Tags: math, hex, memory-address

Suppose you started reading 4 bytes at memory address p and got the following sequence of values: 0x37, 0x13, 0xad, 0xde. What is the 32-bit hex value that is stored at p?

Now how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on used (CPU) architecture. It could be:

```
0x3713ADDE
```

on MSB (Most Significant Byte first) architecture or:

```
0xDEAD1337
```

on LSB (Least Significant Byte first) architecture.